# Trying setValue from an array of variables to multiple cells in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get multiple values from different cells in a sheet in Google Sheets and add in another sheet, but I couldn't figure out how to do it with setValue and getValue functions.

```
function Formulario() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var formCadastro = ss.getSheetByName("Cadastro2");
    var dataS = ss.getSheetByName("Base1");
    
      var cellNome = formCadastro.getRange("B4");
      var cellSobrenome = formCadastro.getRange("B5");

      var arrayCells = [
        cellNome,
        cellSobrenome
      ];
    
  dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,2).setValue(arrayCells.getValue());
}
```

And if I use, I don't get any value from the variables added to Base1, only a new row:

```
   dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,2).setValue(arrayCells);
```

Before I was using **appendRow()** and added **.getValue()** after the variables in the array, but I was getting problems with the other function I create to clean all the cells after saving, using **for** and **getRange**.

Was something like:

```
      var arrayCells = [
        cellNome.getValue(),
        cellSobrenome.getValue()
      ];

    dataS.appendRow(arrayCells);
```

And the function to clean the cells, but it doesn't work with variable.getValue():

```
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < arrayCells.length ; i++ ) {
      arrayCells[i].clearContent();
    }
```

Comment: I think an image of what you are attempting to accomplish might help a lot because your words are not getting me there.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables makes **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data, your question may be closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Formulario() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("Cadastro2");
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange("B4:B5").getValues();
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Base1");
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, vs1.length, vs1[0].length).setValue(vs1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var cellNome = formCadastro.getRange("B4").getValue();
var cellSobrenome = formCadastro.getRange("B5").getValue();

var arrayCells = [
  cellNome,
  cellSobrenome
];
    
dataS.getRange(dataS.getLastRow()+1,1,1,2).setValues([arrayCells]);
```